# Is it possible to remove theme from React test renderer?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, unit-testing, jestjs, react-native-elements

I'm writing some unit tests in React native using the recommended `react-test-renderer`, a whole bunch of our components are using the `react-native-elements` library to provide controls.

What I'm finding however, is that in my small snapshot tests, that the theme object is most of the content, and makes it harder to see the actual changes. I'm wondering if anyone knows a way of turning this off?

The only idea I've so far, is to wrap every single test in a `ThemeProvider` and provide it with a blank theme, which is a lot of boilerplate.

Here's an example snapshot

```
exports[`LocationInfo renders correctly 1`] = `
<Text
  style={Object {}}
  theme={
    Object {
      "colors": Object {
        "disabled": "hsl(208, 8%, 90%)",
        "divider": "#bcbbc1",
        "error": "#ff190c",
        "grey0": "#393e42",
        "grey1": "#43484d",
        "grey2": "#5e6977",
        "grey3": "#86939e",
        "grey4": "#bdc6cf",
        "grey5": "#e1e8ee",
        "greyOutline": "#bbb",
        "platform": Object {
          "android": Object {
            "error": "#f44336",
            "primary": "#2196f3",
            "secondary": "#9C27B0",
            "success": "#4caf50",
            "warning": "#ffeb3b",
          },
          "ios": Object {
            "error": "#ff3b30",
            "primary": "#007aff",
            "secondary": "#5856d6",
            "success": "#4cd964",
            "warning": "#ffcc00",
          },
        },
        "primary": "#2089dc",
        "searchBg": "#303337",
        "secondary": "#8F0CE8",
        "success": "#52c41a",
        "warning": "#faad14",
      },
    }
  }
>
  KEY/100, Main Building
</Text>
`;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a mock of the HOC which passes the received props and probably adding some mock theme

```
const mockHOC = WrappedComponent => {
  const ThemedComponent = (props) => (
    <WrappedComponent {...props} theme="omitted" />
  );
  ThemedComponent.displayName = `MockThemed(${WrappedComponent.displayName ||  WrappedComponent.name || 'Component'})`
  return ThemedComponent;
};
```

### 1. You can use spyOn to attach mock implementation to withTheme

**`jest.setup.js`** ([setupFilesAfterEnv](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#setupfilesafterenv-array))

```
import RNE from 'react-native-elements';

const mockHOC = // ....;
jest.spyOn(RNE, 'withTheme').mockImplementation(mockHOC)
```

### 2. You can try defining [a global mock](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-node-modules)

**`__mocks__/react-native-elements/config/withTheme.js`**

```js
const mockHOC = // ....;
export default jest.fn(mockHOC)
```

Comment: @Ian sorry,  but haven't tested my answer

Comment: No worries, that looks like an interesting approach, so I'll go give it a try :) Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately these approaches don't work. I'm think because the export is defined `default export withTheme(Text)` for example, that the `withTheme` HoC has already been executed before I get a chance to mock it.